# Launchpad says I don't have an SSH key, but I do

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, public-key, launchpad, bzr

I keep trying to push to launchpad (or even connect via SSH), I keep getting an error:

```
Launchpad user 'tay' doesn't have a registered SSH key
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Thing is, I DO have a registered SSH key on launchpad. How do I fix this?

Comment: How did you register your ssh-key. What ssh software are you using.

Comment: Do you have the matching private key installed on the system you are trying to connect from? On Linux your private key should go into the `~/.ssh` folder.

Comment: I have the proper private key. Conencting to Github with the same key pair works perfectly fine. As for my software, I'm using OpenSSH.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a RSA key i.e. your private key should be ~/.ssh/id_rsa. I had a problem because my key was DSA i.e. id_dsa. You can generate it with: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "youremail@example.com"`
2. Ho to your Launchpad account and edit SSH key https://launchpad.net/~yourusername/+editsshkeys
3. Add contends of ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub here
4. You can try to connect with ssh: `ssh -v yourusername@git.launchpad.net` and if connection was successful it returned exit status code -1